# Transit Visa (Toronto - Lisbon - Vienna - Delhi)

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, transit-visas

I am an Indian citizen travelling from Toronto to Delhi. I have a valid Canadian long term Visa. I am thinking of booking a flight from Toronto to Lisbon, Lisbon to Vienna, Vienna to New Delhi. I'm wondering if I will be asked for an Airport Transit Visa?

It seems the connecting flights are from the same terminal and the layover is less than 4 hours on both connections in Vienna and Lisbon.

Comment: Note: you enter in Schengen in Lisbon, and you exit in Vienna, so you will be more then 4 hours in Schengen

Answer (score 4):

This itinerary requires a regular Schengen short stay visa, not just a transit visa.

It would require you to enter the Schengen area at Lisbon, take an internal flight to Vienna, and then exit the Schengen area.